"require is not defined" error when installing package local, works for npm or git
I forked a repo of an npm package and did some changes.
Now I tried to add my verson of the package by adding an Submodule to my project and linking the package via npm install ../dependencys/abcjs
However this dose not work and 'require is not defined' is what I get when visiting the site.

When I include the original package it works.
When I include the fork as a git url it also works.

I also did an npm install in the submodule, if the problem where because of missing dependencys.
Ther fork is on github
(link gose to current commit, since I probably start committing to develop until I understand what the problem is…)

I currently don't think that is part of the problem, but I use svelte which uses vite.

Edit
The code where I use this is also on github
I added 3 versions of the package to my project
"abcjs": "file:../dependencys/abcjs",
"abcjs-test": "npm:abcjs@^6.3.0", 
"abcjs-test2": "git+https://github.com/LokiMidgard/abcjs.git",

the first is the local link, the second the original package and the third how I add it from git. While testing I switch between those.

Can you share the actual code where you're using require to import the package? Seems like you're mixing NodeJS which has require with vanilla JS which does not.

@l3l_aze I added a link to github with the code that uses the package.

IDK Svelte/Vite, but it looks like an issue from Vite which has a might-work plugin to attempt to fix it.
